# How do I remove() an HTML element and then prepend() it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Basically what I need to do is to "move" an HTML element, not position-wise but location of it's DOM structure.

Eg

```
<table id="main">
<tr id="row1"><td></td></tr>
<tr id="row2"><td></td></tr>
<tr id="row3"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

How do I move "tr#row3" to the top of "table#main"?
Can use jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
$('#main tbody').prepend(function() {
    return $(this).find('#row3');
});
```

or you could also do:

```
$('#main tbody').prepend($('#row3'));
```

as IDs are supposed to be unique.

Note that although you don't specify a `tbody` element, the browser will *always* insert one. That's why you cannot just prepend the row to the `table` element.

**Update:** To be correct, in fact you can, as @Šime Vidas pointed out.

**Reference:**  [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Interesting. But I assume that it's just the browser correcting that.

Comment: Accepted for the cleanest answer: $('#main tbody').prepend($('#row3'));

Answer (score 4):

The plain js way is:

```
var row = document.getElementById('row3');
var parent = row.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(row, parent.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var row = table.find("#row3");
var parent = row.parent(); // because parent may not be #main
parent.prepend(row.detach());
```

In general if you want to more an element, while preserving all of its data, you should use the jQuery `.detach()` method <sup>[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)]</sup>. Once you detach the element from its current location it can be inserted into the new one.

However in this case `.prepend()` and `.append()` will actually do what you want by default, so `.detach()` isn't necessary. From the docs:

> If a *single element* selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):

Comment: `table.prepend(row);` probably won't work as every row is in a `tbody`. Try `table.find('tbody').prepend(row);`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Good point. I'm now grabbing the parent before `.detach()`ing.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
var el = $('#row3');
$('#main').prepend(el);
```

Comment: Note that prepend will move it, not copy it. This is the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
var row3 = $("tr#row3")
$("#main").prepend(row3);
row3.remove();
```

is probably the easiest way

Comment: You can't pass a selector to `.prepend`, moreover you remove `row3` completely. http://jsfiddle.net/getaA/

Answer (score 0):

Like this ? :

```
$("#row3").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#row1").before($(this)); 
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Z3VrV/1/

Or this :

```
$("#row3").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(":first-child").before($(this)); 
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Z3VrV/2/